# В чем разница выражений?

Tags: c++

```
template<class Func >
class Tm
{

    Func* funcPtr;

public:
    Tm(Func* func) :funcPtr(func) {};

};
```

Почему когда я пишу так:

```
Tm(Sleep);
```

Компилятор ругается что недостаточно параметров шаблона.

А так все ок:

```
(Tm(Sleep));
```

В чем разница этих выражений?

Comment: В первом случае `Sleep` - это имя переменной. Пишите `Tm{Sleep};` и не мучайтесь

Comment: А почему тогда первый вариант работает? Из за внешних скобок он рассматривает это как выражение, а не объявление?

Comment: Второй вариант уже не будет объявлением переменной.